# Select data from the previous 3 months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I need help selecting data where the date is in the previous 3 months. (note: I'm not asking for the last 3 months i.e. `DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())` )

The reason I don't want to use the DATEADD method is that this query could be run in the middle of the month and I don't want it to return data leading up til that point

Comment: The question isn't a duplicate, the answer was indeed part of another answer to a different question but I fail to see how its a "duplicate"

Comment: Although the *questions* are not exact duplicates of each other, marking questions as a duplicate is helpful for locating great answers such as the one pointed to by Erik which is exactly applicable to your question..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this methodology to determine the first day of 3 months ago, and the last day of the previous month:

```
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-3, 0)   --First day of 3 months ago
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) --Last Day of previous month
```

Then, just use it on your `where` clause.

```
declare @start date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-3, 0)
declare @end date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)

select *
from table
where dateField between @start and @end
```

If your `dateField` is `datetime` then you need to add the seconds, or just add a day and use a `<` operand so you don't miss the last day

```
declare @start date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-3, 0)
declare @end date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)        --First day of current month

select *
from table
where dateField >=@start and dateField < @end
```